# How to make the USB tethering through Android application?

Tags: android, sockets, mobile-application, android-networking, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am developing a application for Android for mobile and tablet. I want to make the USB tethering automatic.

In my application if a user clicks "USB sync" button then the tethering should become enabled automatically.

**I am using Android version 2.3.3 and later.**

It is possible or not?

Comment: Definitely Possible under some conditions. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509924/detect-usb-tethering-on-android) might help you. But i'm not sure its possible on 3.0 or more :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic USB tithering is not possible some latest version of android .**Android 3.0 and later** the automatic USB tithering is not possible.

  So if android version is less than 3.0 means so we use automatic usb tithering.

  **automatic usb tithering is very bad idea,** It have many difficulties,disadvantages,etc.So nobody follow it.

**Im also leave that automatic tithering.**

Answer (score 1):

Just to put it as an answer  :) Definitely Possible under some conditions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509924/detect-usb-tethering-on-android) might help you. But i'm not sure its possible on 3.0 or more :(

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this:
Don't have time to try though:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/TetherSettings.java