# Can I Start a service when usb tethering is enabled?

Tags: android, tethering

I am writing an internal enterprise app and need to start a background service when the user starts usb tethering.

I have not been able to find an intent to listen for which tells me that usb tethering has been started.

I have tried listening for ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, but that doesn't seem to get called for usb tethering either.

Can I get a broadcast to start my service or do I just have to get the user to start tethering before they start my app (which starts the service)?

Comment: this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509924/detect-usb-tethering-on-android

Comment: I had seen this answer, so I guess I'm just going to have to monitor whether usb0 has been set up, if not I'll wait (and maybe notify the user to start tethering)