# Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is there an API to turn On/Off the WiFi HotSpot on Android programmatically?

What methods should I call to turn it On/Off?

**UPDATE:**There's this option to have the HotSpot enabled, and just turn On/Off the WiFi, but this is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946607/android-how-to-turn-on-hotspot-in-android-programmatically

Comment: @mxg,... how is your status right now... is it solved?

Comment: @mxg for Oreo See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo

Answer (score 62):

**Warning This method will not work beyond 5.0, it was a quite dated entry.**

**Use the class below to change/check the `Wifi hotspot` setting:**

```
import android.content.*;
import android.net.wifi.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ApManager {

//check whether wifi hotspot on or off
public static boolean isApOn(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);     
    try {
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifimanager);
    }
    catch (Throwable ignored) {}
    return false;
}

// toggle wifi hotspot on or off
public static boolean configApState(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
    try {  
        // if WiFi is on, turn it off
        if(isApOn(context)) {               
            wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }               
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);                   
        method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, !isApOn(context));
        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return false;
}
} // end of class
```

**You need to add the permissions below to your AndroidMainfest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Use this standalone ApManager class from anywhere as follows:**

```
ApManager.isApOn(YourActivity.this); // check Ap state :boolean
ApManager.configApState(YourActivity.this); // change Ap state :boolean
```

**Hope this will help someone**

Comment: your answer is quite long... but the owner of the question seems don't see it as an answer @AshishSahu?

Comment: It is working for me! thanks and I have to disable wifi function first before run the wifi in AP mode. Otherwise I got error: Failed to start soft AP with a running supplicant

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the following permission to make it work on Android 6: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: This no longer works in Android 6+. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35504709/4307173. Instead of ACTION_SETTINGS, use ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK

Comment: @KenKenKen This is wrong, I just tested this on a Nexus 5X with 7.1.1, it is however necessary that you give `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission which requires the user to accept specifically.

Comment: I can't get Galaxy S9 to start hotspot programmatically! (using Pie or 10)

Comment: Is there any method to disconnect connected device from a hotspot?

Comment: wificonfiguration  always null here thats why i get NoSuchMethodException for setWifiApEnabled...
what should i do?

Answer (score 10):

Here's the complete solution if you want to implement the wifi hotspot feature programmatically in your android app.

**SOLUTION FOR API < 26:**

For devices < API 26. There is no public API by Android for this purpose. So, in order to work with those APIs you've to access private APIs through **reflection**. It is not recommended but if you've no other options left, then here's a trick.

First of all, you need to have this permission in your manifest,

```
  <uses-permission  
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"  
  tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Here's how you can ask it on run-time:

```
 private boolean showWritePermissionSettings() {    
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M  
    && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { 
  if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {    
    Log.v("DANG", " " + !Settings.System.canWrite(this));   
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));  
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    this.startActivity(intent); 
    return false;   
  } 
}   
return true; //Permission already given 
}
```

You can then access the `setWifiEnabled` method through reflection. This returns true if the action you asked for is being process correctly i.e. enabling/disabling hotspot.

```
     public boolean setWifiEnabled(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, boolean enabled) { 
 WifiManager wifiManager;
try {   
  if (enabled) { //disables wifi hotspot if it's already enabled    
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);  
  } 

   Method method = wifiManager.getClass()   
      .getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);   
  return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfig, enabled); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
  Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e); 
  return false; 
}   
}
```

You can also get the wificonfiguration of your hotspot through reflection. I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367449/10936389) that method for this question on StackOverflow.

*P.S: If you don't want to turn on hotspot programmatically, you can start this [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367394/10936389)  and open the wifi settings screen for user to turn it on manually.*

**SOLUTION FOR API >= 26:**

Finally, android released an official API for versions >= Oreo. You can just use the public exposed API by android i.e. [startLocalOnlyHotspot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%2520android.os.Handler)

It turns on a local hotspot without internet access. Which thus can be used to host a server or transfer files.

It requires `Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions.

Here's a simple example of how you can turn on hotspot using this API.

```
private WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiConfiguration currentConfig;
WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation hotspotReservation;
```

The method to turn on hotspot:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void turnOnHotspot() {

      wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
          super.onStarted(reservation);
          hotspotReservation = reservation;
          currentConfig = hotspotReservation.getWifiConfiguration();

          Log.v("DANG", "THE PASSWORD IS: "
              + currentConfig.preSharedKey
              + " \n SSID is : "
              + currentConfig.SSID);

          hotspotDetailsDialog();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
          super.onStopped();
          Log.v("DANG", "Local Hotspot Stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
          super.onFailed(reason);
          Log.v("DANG", "Local Hotspot failed to start");
        }
      }, new Handler());
    }
`
```

Here's how you can get details of the locally created hotspot

```
private void hotspotDetaisDialog()
{

    Log.v(TAG, context.getString(R.string.hotspot_details_message) + "\n" + context.getString(
              R.string.hotspot_ssid_label) + " " + currentConfig.SSID + "\n" + context.getString(
              R.string.hotspot_pass_label) + " " + currentConfig.preSharedKey);

}
```

If it throws, a security exception even after giving the required permissions then you should try enabling your location using GPS. Here's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367371/10936389).

Recently, I've developed a demo app called [Spotserve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367394/10936389). That turns on wifi hotspot for all devices with API>=15 and hosts a demo server on that hotspot. You can check that for more details. Hope this helps!

Comment: and how to connect to the local only hotspot within app. and also how to set specific ssid and password

Comment: is it possible off hotspot for specify device?

Comment: The API >= 26 method worked, but I needed to initialize the wifiManager first: 

wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: @AdeelZafar, with the `startLocalOnlyHotspot` method, is there a way to configure the SSID/password?

Answer (score 4):

Warning This method will not work beyond 5.0, it was a quite dated entry.

You can use the following code to enable, disable and query the wifi direct state programatically.

```
package com.kusmezer.androidhelper.networking;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

public final class WifiApManager {
      private static final int WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED = 4;
      private final WifiManager mWifiManager;
      private final String TAG = "Wifi Access Manager";
      private Method wifiControlMethod;
      private Method wifiApConfigurationMethod;
      private Method wifiApState;

      public WifiApManager(Context context) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
       context = Preconditions.checkNotNull(context);
       mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       wifiControlMethod = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class,boolean.class);
       wifiApConfigurationMethod = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration",null);
       wifiApState = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");
      }   
      public boolean setWifiApState(WifiConfiguration config, boolean enabled) {
       config = Preconditions.checkNotNull(config);
       try {
        if (enabled) {
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(!enabled);
        }
        return (Boolean) wifiControlMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, config, enabled);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        return false;
       }
      }
      public WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration()
      {
          try{
              return (WifiConfiguration)wifiApConfigurationMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, null);
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              return null;
          }
      }
      public int getWifiApState() {
       try {
            return (Integer)wifiApState.invoke(mWifiManager);
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            return WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED;
       }
      }
}
```

Comment: @ldce Reflection it's not an API. Feathermore, I checked it on Nexus 5 with Lollipop and it still works.

Comment: @Divers it works on Nexus 5 with Lollipop? Doesn't work on my AT&T S6 Lollipop 5.1.1

Comment: Probably they removed it in the new releases

Comment: why do you post an example with third party library `com.google.common.base.Preconditions;`?

Comment: It is a quite dated entry, so basically it will not work with the new versions.

Answer (score 4):

For Android 8.0, there is a new API to handle Hotspots. As far as I know, the old way using reflection doesn't work anymore.
Please refer to:

Android Developers
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%20android.os.Handler)

```
void startLocalOnlyHotspot (WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback callback, 
                Handler handler)
```

> Request a local only hotspot that an application can use to communicate between co-located devices connected to the created WiFi hotspot. The network created by this method will not have Internet access.

Stack Overflow
[How to turn on/off wifi hotspot programmatically in Android 8.0 (Oreo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo?rq=1)

> onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) method will be called if hotspot is turned on.. Using WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reference you call close() method to turn off hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me:

```
WifiConfiguration apConfig = null;
Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, Boolean.TYPE);
method.invoke(wifimanager, apConfig, true);
```

Comment: if that's the way you could turn on the Wifi Hotspot, then... how could you turn it off?

Comment: This is working till the Android 4.4 only. From Android 5.0 and above versions it is not working to connect to the hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

## APManager - Access Point Manager

Step 1 : Add the jcenter repository to your build file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Step 2 : Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.vkpapps.wifimanager:APManager:1.0.0'
}
```

Step 3 use in your app

```java
APManager apManager = APManager.getApManager(this);
apManager.turnOnHotspot(this, new APManager.OnSuccessListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String ssid, String password) {
        //write your logic
    }

}, new APManager.OnFailureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int failureCode, @Nullable Exception e) {
        //handle error like give access to location permission,write system setting permission,
        //disconnect wifi,turn off already created hotspot,enable GPS provider
        
        //or use DefaultFailureListener class to handle automatically
    }

});
```

check out source code
https://github.com/vijaypatidar/AndroidWifiManager

Comment: This creates the hotspot but didn't share the internet connectivity of the mobile data.

Comment: I love this answer <3

Comment: @KrunalShah This library internally uses LocalHotspot API for Andoird 8.0+ which didn’t allow sharing internet.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be looking at the WifiManager class. Specifically the `setWifiEnabled(bool)` function.

See the documentation at:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29)

A tutorial on how to use it (including what permissions you need) can be found here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210228070142/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using.html

Comment: Is it possible without turning On/Off the WiFi?

Comment: Possibly, still using the WifiManager class. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023226/android-2-2-wifi-hotspot-api (I think that's your best bet.)

Comment: he talks about WiFi hotspot, not just WiFi

Answer (score 1):

I have publish unofficial api's for same, it's contains more than just hotspot turn `on/off`. [link](https://github.com/mady4ever/android-testhotspot)

For API's DOC - [link](http://mady4ever.github.io/TestHotspotdoc).

Comment: Note that the provided API is for the device acting as a client connecting to an AP, while the OP was looking for ways to control the built-in AP.

Answer (score 0):

**For Oreo & PIE ** I found below way [through this](https://gist.github.com/kimcy929/404c75001499f8d5bbfc4c8181f0f55b)

```
private WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation mReservation;
private boolean isHotspotEnabled = false;
private final int REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION_SYSTEM_SETTINGS = 101;

private boolean isLocationPermissionEnable() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void turnOnHotspot() {
    if (!isLocationPermissionEnable()) {
        return;
    }
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (manager != null) {
        // Don't start when it started (existed)
        manager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
                super.onStarted(reservation);
                //Log.d(TAG, "Wifi Hotspot is on now");
                mReservation = reservation;
                isHotspotEnabled = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
                super.onStopped();
                //Log.d(TAG, "onStopped: ");
                isHotspotEnabled = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(int reason) {
                super.onFailed(reason);
                //Log.d(TAG, "onFailed: ");
                isHotspotEnabled = false;
            }
        }, new Handler());
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void turnOffHotspot() {
    if (!isLocationPermissionEnable()) {
        return;
    }
    if (mReservation != null) {
        mReservation.close();
        isHotspotEnabled = false;
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void toggleHotspot() {
    if (!isHotspotEnabled) {
        turnOnHotspot();
    } else {
        turnOffHotspot();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void enableLocationSettings() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    /*mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);*/
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
            .setAlwaysShow(false); // Show dialog

    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task= LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
        try {
            LocationSettingsResponse response = task1.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
            // requests here.
            toggleHotspot();

        } catch (ApiException exception) {
            switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                    // user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(HotspotActivity.this, REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION_SYSTEM_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION_SYSTEM_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    toggleHotspot();
                    Toast.makeText(HotspotActivity.this,states.isLocationPresent()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    Toast.makeText(HotspotActivity.this,"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

UseAge

```
btnHotspot.setOnClickListenr(view -> {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Step 1: Enable the location settings use Google Location Service
        // Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps/50796199#50796199
        // Step 3: If OK then check the location permission and enable hotspot
        // Step 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843271/how-to-turn-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo-setwifiapen
        enableLocationSettings();
        return;
    }
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can programmatically turn on and off

```
setWifiApDisable.invoke(connectivityManager, TETHERING_WIFI);//Have to disable to enable
setwifiApEnabled.invoke(connectivityManager, TETHERING_WIFI, false, mSystemCallback,null);
```

Using callback class, to programmatically  turn on hotspot in pie(9.0) u need to turn off programmatically and the switch on.

Comment: Provide some more information on the code you added here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console and service for that option.

I think with this you can solve that. I made a test directly in console and enable hotspot

I found this in this article 
[Is it possible to USB tether an android device using adb through the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226924/is-it-possible-to-usb-tether-an-android-device-using-adb-through-the-terminal)

And after read the interface we can use the same 24 but needs more parameters

> service call connectivity 24 i32 0 i32 1 i32 0 s16 random

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line with root access

To turn on hotspot.

```
adb shell su -c service call connectivity 24 i32 0 i32 0 i32 0 s16 random
```

To turn off hotspot

```
adb shell su -c service call connectivity 25 i32 0 i32 0 i32 0 s16 random
```

Comment: can u explain what "24 i32 0 i32 0 i32 0" is mean?

Answer (score -3):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

where status may be `true` or `false`

add permission manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />`

Comment: That only turns wifi on/off, not the HotSpot.