# How do I enable/disable USB tethering on android 5.1.1 programmatically?

Tags: android, usb, adb, tethering, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I need a way to enable/disable tethering via API. Most of the solutions posted here have been applicable to android 4.4 or below.

I've already gone through the following solutions (none worked):

- [Is it possible to USB tether an android device using adb through the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226924/is-it-possible-to-usb-tether-an-android-device-using-adb-through-the-terminal)
- [Detect USB tethering on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509924/detect-usb-tethering-on-android)
- [Enable/Disable USB or Wifi tethering programmatically on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531801/enable-disable-usb-or-wifi-tethering-programmatically-on-android)

I'm aware that the API supporting this is typically only for system apps (regular apps don't have the MANAGE_USB permission), but is there any way to go about this for android 5.1.1?

Comment: Well see these [1][1] and [2][2]. They Explain what u need...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436280/start-stop-built-in-wi-fi-usb-tethering-from-code
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049547/how-i-can-enable-usb-tethering-programmatically-on-an-android-4-0-device

Comment: This reads like "I know the answer to my question but I don't like it. Give me another answer"

Comment: Well, did you also read the part where I mentioned that none of the posted solutions worked and I was asking if there were any alternatives?