# Reading Wifi Rssi

Tags: android

Hello I was wondering if anyone could tell me is it possible to read the wifi rssi from another android phone. I am trying to build a simple app that reads the wifi rssi and then uses this to calculate into a distance, I have looked up the WifiManager, TelephonyManager class and the NeighbouringCellInfo, I have even tried to implement a couple of tutorials to no joy. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.﻿

Comment: I didn't understand the "another android phone". Do you want to obtain the rssi from one android phone, right?

Comment: I read it again and I think now I get it. You want the RSSI not from a fixed beacon, but from another phone's wifi, right?

Comment: Yes that's right I want to be able to use the app on one phone to read the wifi rssi from another phone, I will then hopefully use this to work out a distance. I will eventually bring more phones in to see if I can use them for trilateration to pin point where a single phone is at a point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this will be possible only with **Wi-Fi hotspot** enable, since this is the only way another phone can see another via Wi-Fi.

If you want to try it out see this thread that helps enabling Wi-Fi hotspot.

[Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically)

Another thing you might consider is **bluetooth RSSI**.

Activating **bluetooth** is more straightforward and can give more precise accuracy (but covers less space).