# In android Lollipop is there a way to turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

as mentioned here:[Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically)
a comment say,the Reflection api is not working in Lollipop.

I want to know is there a way to do this in Lollipop

Comment: 5.1.1 and 6.0 allows only system applications to change the state. Exactly as it was with GPS. So the 'root' required...