# How do I change the Portable Hotspot's SSID in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I want change the Hotspot SSID! Can anybody help?

From [Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically), here is my code to toggle the Portable Hotspot:

```
import android.content.*;import android.net.wifi.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ApManager {

//check whether wifi hotspot on or off
public static boolean isApOn(Context context) {
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager)  context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);     
try {
    Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifimanager);
}
catch (Throwable ignored) {}
return false;
}

// toggle wifi hotspot on or off
public static boolean configApState(Context context) {
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
try {  
    // if WiFi is on, turn it off
    if(isApOn(context)) {               
        wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }               
    Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);                   
    method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, !isApOn(context));
    return true;
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
return false;
}
} // end of class
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best place to look for clues is in the AOSP source code itself. Here's the relevant part: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#1147

The following code worked for me:

```
public static boolean setHotspotName(String newName, Context context) { 
    try {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Method getConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager);

        wifiConfig.SSID = newName;

        Method setConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration", WifiConfiguration.class);
        setConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfig);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the following lines into your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: I forgot to add: you may piss off your user when she realises that her Portable Hotspot name has been inexplicably changed the next time she tried to tether and cannot find the usual SSID. Tread carefully here.

Comment: But can u please say me where to call

Comment: Where to call what? You can just call `setHotspotName` as given above whenever you want to change the Hotspot SSID. Surely __you__ decide where __you__ want that to happen?

Comment: Sorry, it does work. I actually tested this. Please give us the details of why it doesn't work for you then we might be able to help.

Comment: How to make hotspot security open?

Comment: Can I use wifiConfig.wepKeys[0] to change the hotspot password as well?

Comment: @Saran are there any methods to on and off hotspot programmatically?