# Setup an Android WiFi Hotspot and get login Information

Tags: android

How do i set up a hotspot in Android by using code and how can i get infornations about a failed log in? Say, someone want's to connect to the hotspot but is using a wrong password.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should provide examples of what you have tried and show that you have tried to to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Nah, i would, but i am not familiar with Android at all, just Java. I just wanted to test some things.

Comment: Then instead I would suggest trying to research the problem before posting a question.

Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23651004/2291915

Comment: Already came across this but i forgot to mention. My fault, thank's anyways. But i still wanna get some information if somebody is trying to log in into my hotspot.