# start Hot Spot programatically in android 7.1

Tags: android

How we can start hotspot on Rooted Android 7.1.I have done this on android 7.0 but not on 7.1.1.Any idea would be big help for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically)

Comment: No,This work on Android 7.0 not on 7.1.1

Comment: Just to note - there are no official API methods to do that, and unofficial hacks may be removed from Android any moment.

Comment: Ok Vladyslav,But any hack we have to implement on 7.1 So that we can start hotspot on android 7.1.1 for now.It.