# How to ON/OFF hotspot without giving WRITE_SETTINGS permission in Marshmallow?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to ON/OFF hotspot in android Marshmallow 6.0 (API level 23)  but I am unable to find any proper working solution.
Is there anyone who can provide me a proper working code for it?
appreciate it.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: thx fro answering but that needs me to ask from user for write settings permission but i dont want that. i want a direct approach