# Mobile Hotspot Name and Password

Tags: android, wifimanager, hotspot

I have to get the name and password of my mobile hotspot programmatically in android studio. How do I do it?

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
  
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
Toast.makeText(this,"SSID:"+wifiInfo.getSSID(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code gives me SSID of wifi I am connected to. I need name of my Mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the wificonfiguration of your hotspot in API<26 using reflection. Its not the recommended way but if you need it bad, then here it is.

```
private WifiConfiguration currentConfig;
```

```
  private WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration() {  
    try {   
      Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");   
      return (WifiConfiguration) method.invoke(wifiManager);    
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e); 
      return null;  
    }   
  }
```

And then you can use the **WifiConfiguration** object to get its details:

```
currentConfig.SSID
currentConfig.preSharedKey
```