# How to open Android Settings Wifi Hotspot Menu Pragmatically in Java?

Tags: java, android, wifi, hotspot

I want to open below [image]
or if this is not possible then below settings 
[image]

through java code in android. I know i can open settings using

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

but i am not able to find appropriate strings for either of the above menus. Please if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`