# On Android 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, how to open android Ap progmatically or Go to Settings->More...->Portable Wi-Fi hotspot by code?

Tags: android, wifi, settings

The only possible solution is :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); 
    //Is there any value for entering hotsopt?

    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Please note (`ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)):

> Activity Action: Show settings to allow configuration of wireless
>   controls such as Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Mobile networks.
>
> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.

Comment: ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS just entered the first Wifi settings. Thanks.

Comment: Was that what you were looking for? You should use the accept answer if that is the case btw. I'm not sure if you can go straight into Hotspots, looking at the Settings link in the answer I guess the different data or wireless settings is the only way.

Comment: I get a way on Android2.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023226/android-2-2-wifi-hotspot-api/3388910#3388910 But it do not worked on My Android 4.03 pad. Thank you